# Custom validation method not included if called in 2 validate statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

As the title says, I am trying to reuse my custom validation method in a Rails 4 model.
I have a situation similar to this:

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  RESOURCE_TYPE = ["webpage", "image", "video", "paragraph"]

  validates :type, presence: true
  validate :always_invalid, if: :webpage?
  validate :always_invalid, if: :image?

  def always_invalid
    binding.pry
    errors.add(:data, "Invalid")
  end

  # methods for type checking
  RESOURCE_TYPE.each do |res_type|
    define_method("#{res_type}?") { self.type == res_type }
  end
end
```

I expect that this will fail the validation for objects where type is `webpage` or `image`. However, when I try to run, only object with `image` for type is invalidated.

```
> a
=> #<Resource id: nil, type: "webpage", data: {:url=>"http://morar.net/forest"}, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
> a.webpage?
=> true
> a.valid?
=> true


> b
=> #<Resource id: nil, type: "image", data: {:url=>"http://powlowski.info/colleen.langworth/nulla.png"}, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
> b.image?
=> true
> b.valid?

From: /home/mark/source/summer/app/models/resource.rb @ line 13 Resource#always_invalid:

    12: def always_invalid
 => 13:   binding.pry
    14:   errors.add(:data, "Invalid")
    15:   # return false
    16: end

> exit
=> false
```

So it seems that only the last validate: statement is working.

Changing the order of the 2 validate statement turn things around: object of type `webpage` is invalidated while those with `image` for type doesn't.

It would be great if you can explain why it happened.

Thanks

PS: My schema, in case you need it:

```
create_table "resources", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "type"
  t.json     "data"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Comment: Call the methods in your always_invalid method. It happens because that's how validate is implemented, it doesn't "build up" a collection of validations per custom method, it's a single entry.

Comment: do you mean that I can only use the validate statement once?

Comment: @DaveNewton, thanks: I read the source code in ActiveModel.
it seems that because: `set_callback(:validate, *args, &block)`, I can only call it once. I am switching to use a custom validator class

Answer (score 0):

you can just use proc in :if or alias the method name

Comment: oh, how would the proc for :if be like?

Comment: you can try this

validate :dummy_validation, if: Proc.new { |record| record.send(:condition1_met?) || record.send(:condition2_met?) }

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, following code will work

validate :conditional_validation

def conditional_validation

if condition1
      self.validation1 # your self.errors.add(..) should be in validation1
      self.validation2
   elsif condition1
      self.validation3
      self.validation4
   ...
   end

end